# What (or who) is the rival gang of the Jets?

Tags: single-word-requests, pronouns, questions, who

Is a gang (or a musical group) considered like a person or an object? I.e. should I ask:

> **Who** is the rival gang of the Jets?

Or should it be:

> **What** is the rival gang of the Jets?

What is the grammatically correct form?

Comment: A "gang" is usually a street-level crime organization like the Crips or the Aryan Brotherhood...are you sure of your terminology ? did you meant "band" ?

Comment: Are you talking about *West Side Story*?  The rival gang to the Jets is the Sharks.

Comment: I'm not sure what the question is -  are you looking for a grammatically correct way to ask who or what someone's antagonist is, or are you looking for a word that refer tot that antagonist (enemy/mies, opponent(s)?  Going purely on the title question, I am inclined to refer you to [a wiki page on West Side Story](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/West_Side_Story). Please try to clarify your question by elaborating on what exactly you are looking for.

Comment: Thank you for your answers. I'm looking for a grammatically correct way to ask who or what when talking about gangs, groups....

Comment: Does your question read like you are looking for a grammatically correct way to ask **who** or **what** when talking about gangs or groups?

Comment: Yes, it does Rathony.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's asking for trivia, and he nothing to do with language.

Comment: Jimm101, I wasn't asking for trivia. It's a real question and I just needed some hlep...

Comment: Look at the edited post. You should have asked that way.

Comment: The title makes it sound like you just want to know the name of the rival gang.  If you'd titled it **"Do we say 'who' or 'what' when referring to a gang?"** it would have been much clearer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After some initial confusion and editorial intervention, it appears that the question asks whether a named collection of folk is singular or plural.

The tendency is to render as plural when the name has a plural ending, and as singular when it doesn't.

> **The Rolling Stones are performing tonight.**
>
> **The Jets challenge the Sharks to a rumble.**

but

> **Buffalo Springfield was his favorite band in the 1960s.**
>
> **The Miami Heat plays better at home than away.**

Following a comment from the Original Poster, I'll add that the collective is normally treated as **people**.

> **who are the Rolling Stones?**

Comment: It wasn't my question but I wasn't clear enough. However your answer is interesting.

Comment: Your last comment is very useful. It's what I wanted to know!

Comment: You might find that the British would disagree with your answer.  They would likely say The Miami Heat play better at home.  In fact, they'd say Manchester United play better at home, too.

Comment: "The Heat plays better at home than away." is *not* natural in USAEng today, I don't think. It would usually be "The Heat play better at home." Hi Steven.  It's tricky. "The Heat play better at home" is natural. However "The Miami Heat are playing great tonight" is natural.  One complicating factor is that in USAEng, there's a recognized "added drama" when you choose the singular possibility in such cases.  (It has a somewhat "military" drama, or "businesswise English" feel one could say - terribly American, emphasizing one entity when discussing a group.)

Comment: @JoeBlow - I agree, it's tricky. And sportscasters are still trying to wrap their tongues around those teams with singular-sounding names. After growing up in the domain of the (mispronounced) Celtics, it's *wicked* hard for me too, and I feel their malaise. Just remember that "Sox" is plural, and Liverpool is...don't talk to me about Liverpool.

Answer (score 3):

If you wanted to know who the members of a band were, you could ask

**Who is in Pink Floyd?**

If you wanted to know which group a person belongs to:

**What band is David Byrne with?**

**Who is David Byrne with?**

You could also ask

**Who was the closing act at Woodstock?**

**What was the closing act at Woodstock?**

Comment: So they are both grammatically correct?

Comment: Yes, you can think of an ensemble either as an abstract entity (what) or as a number of human beings doing something together (who).

Comment: Nobody now, used to be the Talking Heads, Jimi!